# Trying to use SCN_MODIFIED with pyqt6 generates a TypeError crash

Tags: python, qscintilla, pyqt6

I've got a simple editor that I'm trying to port to PyQt6, but have run into a problem with the document modified message.  It works fine in PyQt5 but generates `'TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant back to a Python object'` message in PyQt6.

```
# from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
# from PyQt6.Qsci import QsciScintilla
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla


class SimplePythonEditor(QsciScintilla):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.SCN_MODIFIED.connect(self._modified)


    # The current documentation https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCN_MODIFIED shows a slightly different set of arguments and order.
    # def _modified(self, modificationType, position, length, linesAdded, text, line, foldLevelNow, foldLevelPrev):
    def _modified(self, position, modificationType, text, length, linesAdded, line, foldLevelNow, foldLevelPrev, token, annotationLinesAdded):        
        print(f'_modified {modificationType=}, {position=}, {length=}, {linesAdded=}, {text=}, {line=}, {foldLevelNow=}, {foldLevelPrev=}, {token=}, {annotationLinesAdded=}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    editor = SimplePythonEditor()
    editor.show()
    app.exec()
```

Running the code and typing abc in PyQt5 generates the following output

```
_modified modificationType=1048576, position=0, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=None, line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=1040, position=0, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=None, line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=8209, position=0, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=b'a', line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=1048576, position=1, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=None, line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=1040, position=1, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=None, line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=17, position=1, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=b'b', line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=1048576, position=2, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=None, line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=1040, position=2, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=None, line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
_modified modificationType=17, position=2, length=1, linesAdded=0, text=b'c', line=0, foldLevelNow=0, foldLevelPrev=0, token=0, annotationLinesAdded=0
```

I'm on linux my package versions used

```
PyQt5==5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
QScintilla==2.13.0
```

```
PyQt6==6.1.1
PyQt6-Qt6==6.1.2
PyQt6-QScintilla==2.13.0
```

Comment: It is clearly a bug, I recommend you report it

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for the sanity check.  I always assume I've done something wrong or missed a comment in release notes before jumping to it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `send.SendScintilla(self.SCI_SETMODEVENTMASK, SC_MOD_INSERTTEXT | self.SC_MOD_DELETETEXT)` after `self.SCN_MODIFIED.connect(self._modified)`

without any of the following 4 flags works without error.
SC_MOD_CHANGESTYLE
SC_MOD_CHANGEFOLD
SC_PERFORMED_USER
SC_MOD_CHANGEMARKER